# Mathematica doesn't simplify even providing the assumption

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I wrote the following:

```
$Assumptions = {nAvg >= 0};
Simplify[Im[1/(8 nAvg)]]
```

And Mathematica returns me: 1/8 Im[1/nAvg]

Why doesn't it simply returns me $0$ ?

Comment: Try `Simplify[ComplexExpand[Im[1/(8 nAvg)]]]` to this end.

Comment: @user64494 thanks it works. But why is this necessary ?

Comment: Or `Simplify[Im[1/(8 nAvg)], Assumptions -> nAvg > 0]` or `Assuming[nAvg > 0, Simplify[Im[1/(8 nAvg)]]]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Assumptions = {nAvg > 0};
Simplify[Im[1/(8 nAvg)]]
```

```
$Assumptions = nAvg ∈ PositiveReals;
Simplify[Im[1/(8 nAvg)]]
```

Maybe when `nAvg==0`,`1/(8 nAvg)` will return Complex Infinity.

Other way such as

```
ComplexExpand[Im[1/(8 nAvg)]]
ComplexExpand[Re[1/(8 nAvg)]]
ComplexExpand[ReIm[1/(8 nAvg)]]
```

work since `ComplexExpand` assume all the variables is in `Reals`.